# Play 2.2 optional url parameters not working

Tags: playframework

I have a little problem with definig optional parameters in Play 2.2.
I followed the example here in the documentation http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaRouting

Here are my route:

```
GET     /customers                  controllers.Api.customers(id: String, type: String ?= "xml", datetime: String ?= "de")
```

and my controller:

```
public class Api extends Controller {   
    public static Result customers(String id, String type, String datetime){
    // code omitted
 }
}
```

Unfortunately, i get a compilation error "illegal start of simple expression " when i call "host/customers?id=2&type=8&datetime=123456", does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers Lizy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `type` is reserved in Scala so you can't name a routing parameter that.  If you rename `type` to something else this should work.

BTW: It seems like Play's routes compiler should have a way to deal with this.  So maybe you should file a bug / feature request: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues

Comment: You made my day! It never crossed my mind, that it could be the name of the parameter. It was an awkward choice for the parameter. Sorry to spam the comment with credits.

Comment: Even using backticks for Scala keywords (\`type\`: String ?= "xml") does not work.